# VS Code. I don't want files in tabs across the top, but in a side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just downloaded VS Code. I've opened a bunch of html files. Each file appears in a tab across the top. I find this a real pain because I can't see the files to the right of my screen without scrolling to the right.

I'm used to using BBEdit where open files appear in a side bar.

Is it possible to have the files appear in a side bar rather than tabs?

Comment: Learn how to ask first. Noe everyone uses BBEdit, so you need to reveal more about what you wanted. BTW, VSCode is not VS.

Comment: But you should already have the files in the explorer bar according to `explorer.openEditors.visible` set to some number.  And then you can set `workbench.editor.showTabs` to false.  Alternatively, if you stick with tabs, look at `workbench.editor.tabSizing` you might like `shrink` better.